# A polymorphic method for creating a list of new objects

Tags: java, object

What is the best way to write a method that given a type T and integer n, returns a list of n newly created objects of type T. Is it possible to pass a constructor as argument or will I have to accomplish this in some other way?

Was thinking something like this

```
public <T> ArrayList<Object> generate(T type, int amount){
    ArrayList<Object> objects = new ArrayList();
    for (int i = 0; i < amount; i ++){
        objects.add(new bla bla)...

}
```

Comment: can we see some codes what you tried so far?

Comment: You can make such thing in c++, here it would have to be separate Template class with only one static method. Parameter for template would be type you want to instantiate, and method would accept only number of elements. Also creation of those elements would have to probably have to go on default constructor.

Comment: You can't pass constructors in Java, or any other functions. You can't pass types, either.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik yes you can, kinda, that's what Reflection is for. I can't say I like to use it, but it is possible.

Comment: @Dariusz Yes it's the "kinda" part why I deliberately filtered that out :) You can't pass them in a typesafe manner, as I think OP would like to.

Answer (score 2):

Use a generic method.

```
public <T> List<T> getList(Class<T> clazz, int size) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException{
    List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();
    for(int x = 0; x < size; x++){
        list.add(clazz.newInstance());
    }
    return list;
}
```

**NOTE:** This will only work for objects with a default constructor.  If you want to create a `List` of objects that do not contain a default constructor you must do so using reflection to pick the appropriate constructor.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static <T> List<T> generate(Class<T> clazz, int amount) {
   ArrayList<Object> objects = new ArrayList();
   for (int i = 0; i < amount; i ++){
      objects.add(clazz.newInstance());
   }
   return list;
}
```

The code above actually tries to use default constructor. You can pass a reflection reference to an appropriate constructor of your choice if you want. A list of constructors can be obtained by calling `Class.getConstructors()`.

Then your code would look like this:

```
public static <T> List<T> generate(Constructor<T> constructor, int amount) {
   ArrayList<Object> objects = new ArrayList();
   for (int i = 0; i < amount; i ++){
      objects.add(constructor.newInstance(param1, param2, ...)); // fill the arguments 
   }
   return list;
}
```